# Generating JAXB classes for XML having same parent tag

Tags: jaxb

I am getting xml input where parent tag is same but other tags are different.
every parent tag has attribute *type* which tells what content you should read.
i have created jaxb classes under different packages based on xml content ,
now problem is as parent class name is same for all ,so while making instance of JAXBContext ,which parent class should i passed ?

while marshelling we can specify if this is my tag then renamed to abc tag by passing annotation {name="abc"} , in same fashion what if i changed parent class name and based on annotation jaxb will unmarshel the xml

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of this. i used binding file. where we can mentioned what should be name of generated class for particular tag.

```
<jxb:bindings 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
version="2.1">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="attribute.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='component']">
            <jxb:class name="MyOwnClass"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```